# How to merge fields from MS Access form onto a Word Document

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I've created a button on a table in my Access database.  It generates a MS Word document, which is a letter. My current process has me completing the form by filling in the name and address on the letter.

I've created a field in the Access form for name and address. Is it possible for the button to create the letter complete with information from the name and address fields in Access?

Essentially, I'm trying to have the letter completed when I press the button by getting rid of the step for me to type the name and address.  If possible, I would really appreciate example SQL code, which I will work into my existing code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Additional Info:  I have the Adobe suite, so if the letter prints as a PDF, that is no problem.

Comment: SQL is used in Access for querying, it won't help with your problem.  Google for mail merge instead.

Comment: @MátéJuhász thank you for the advice.  I've exported the table to an excel sheet and performed a mail merge.  Another option would be to create a report in Access and just put the wording of the letter in there.  Then I can fill in the fields using relationships to the form.